# custom seekbar progress color fades away

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-seekbar

I'm trying to make a custom seekbar which has a ceratin color for showing the progress. I tried it using a layerlist defined in xml. The color of the progress fades away when i run the code.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/load_money_seekbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:thumb="@drawable/load_money_arrow"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_loadmoney">
```

seekbar_loadmoney.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#bbbbbb" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#bbbbbb" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#213D8D" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Please refer th e screen shot 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of research, i got the answer. I wanted my seekbar's progress to be shown programmaticly and the user cannot change the progress of seekbar. So i did this

```
seekbar.setEnabled(false)
```

This makes the color of the progress in the seekbar to fade away. We can achieve the same thing without fading seekbar's progress color by the following code.

```
        seekbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return true;
        }
    });
```